# Setting the Default Major Mode?

Tags: spacemacs, major-mode

I have a lot of files on my system without extensions (i.e., files like `todo`, `list_of_stuff`, etc). I would like these types of files to default to `markdown-mode` for their major mode. How to do this? In case it matters, I'm running spacemacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Emacs "Major Modes" info topic (C-h i d m emacs m major), try adding this to your spacemacs user-config:

```
(setq-default major-mode 'markdown-mode)
```

The "Choosing Modes" info will be a good resource if you need more nuance.